# Retrieving data from SQL database and filling in fields on web form for existing customer

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a web form invoice page based on an Access form the company is currently using. It's going to consist of multiple parts, the customer information, the invoice information and the calculations. Right now I am working on the first part, the customer information. I am trying to make it check for existing customer information based on the lastname field or email field. I have searched for how to retrieve data from SQL database to fill in web form fields using PDO but all that comes up is how to submit data from web form to SQL database using PDO. I have this file to check for existing info without hitting submit, it checks when the cursor leaves the field.
I found a script.js file that uses javascript and ajax to check for existing customer but that will just return that the user already exists, I need it to fill in the data in the other fields if the user exists. I would be very grateful if someone could point me to an article or site that can show me how to change it from just returning "user already exists" to having it fill in the info into the other fields.

I did try to put the code on here but it kept telling me I was formatting it wrong. I tried putting 3 ';s first and tried indenting 8 spaces first but it still told me I was doing it wrong.

Thank you!

Edit: Ok trying to add code again.

Still not working. I hit ctrl+k and it pops up 'add code here', than I paste the code in, hit submit edit and it tells me error in code formatting.

Comment: Welcome. Please retry to add code so we get better idea of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mulli - but let me take a shot at it nevertheless ...

The first part should be the easiest (I'm taking an SQLite database as example) :

```
$DBfullPath = "sqlite:/path/to/database.sqlite" ;
$searchMail = "my.name@provider.com" ;

// create DB handle
if ( !($dbh = new PDO($DBfullPath)) ) 
   throw new Exception("failed to create local DB handle") ;

// prepare SELECT query
$qry =<<<QRYDB
SELECT ID, data 
FROM theTable
WHERE email = :email
QRYDB;

// create prepared statement
$stmt  = $dbh->prepare($qry) ;

// run the prepared statement
if (false === $stmt->execute(array(":email" => $searchMail)) )
   throw new Exception("SELECT failed") ;

// fetch all data matching the search criteria from the statement
$allRows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;

// release the DB handle
$dbh = NULL ;

// process search results
var_dump($allRows) ;
```

For the second part, do I understand correctly that you would like to see a live update of the (partial) form, based on the "live" changes a user is making ? Without the PHP page being reloaded ?

Comment: What did you do to make the code box? I tried the ‘’’ at beginning and end of code and tried hitting Ctrl+k and it made the add code box here and I pasted my code there but it told me I did it wrong no matter what. So how do I make that code box to put the code in please?

Comment: @DeviantlyD : 
- align your code to the left (no spaces),
- on the top of your edit window, click the curly braces {}

Comment: Ok it finally worked by clicking the add javascript snippet button. So now you can get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes try 3 to add the code, hopefully it works.

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
 var lastname_state = false;
 var email_state = false;
 $('#lastname').on('blur', function(){
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
  if (lastname == '') {
   lastname_state = false;
   return;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: 'register.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
     'lastname_check' : 1,
     'lastname' : lastname,
    },
    success: function(response){
      if (response == 'taken' ) {
       lastname_state = false;
       $('#lastname').parent().removeClass();
       $('#lastname').parent().addClass("form_error");
       $('#lastname').siblings("span").text('Sorry... lastname already taken');
      }else if (response == 'not_taken') {
       lastname_state = true;
       $('#lastname').parent().removeClass();
       $('#lastname').parent().addClass("form_success");
       $('#lastname').siblings("span").text('lastname available');
      }
    }
  });
 });  
  $('#email').on('blur', function(){
  var email = $('#email').val();
  if (email == '') {
   email_state = false;
   return;
  }
  $.ajax({
      url: 'register.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
       'email_check' : 1,
       'email' : email,
      },
      success: function(response){
       if (response == 'taken' ) {
          email_state = false;
          $('#email').parent().removeClass();
          $('#email').parent().addClass("form_error");
          $('#email').siblings("span").text('Sorry... Email already taken');
       }else if (response == 'not_taken') {
         email_state = true;
         $('#email').parent().removeClass();
         $('#email').parent().addClass("form_success");
         $('#email').siblings("span").text('Email available');
       }
      }
  });
 });

 $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
  var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
 var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
 var address = $('#address').val();
 var city = $('#city').val();
 var state = $('#state').val();
 var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();
 var license = $('#license').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  if (lastname_state == false || email_state == false) {
   $('#error_msg').text('Fix the errors in the form first');
 }else{
      // proceed with form submission
      $.ajax({
       url: 'register.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
        'save' : 1,
        'lastname' : lastname,
   'firstname' : firstname,
   'address' : address,
   'city' : city,
   'state' : state,
   'zipcode' : zipcode,
   'license' : license,
   'email' : email,
       },
       success: function(response){
        alert('user saved');
        $('#lastname').val('');
   $('#firstname').val('');
   $('#address').val('');
   $('#city').val('');
   $('#state').val('');
   $('#zipcode').val('');
        $('#license').val('');
       }
      });
  }
 });
});
```

If this worked, a little info about this code. It was originally made for registration, just username, email, password. So I added the other fields and removed the password part. Not sure if I did that right but I gave it a try. But mainly when it checks to see if the lastname or email exists, if it doesn't I want it to allow me to finish filling form and submit info as a new record. If lastname or email does exist I want it to fill in the rest of the fields with that customers info rather than just saying that it already exists.

Thanks again!

Edit: Ok the code brackets didn't work for me either, but I clicked the add javascript snippet and that worked, so there is the code at least. Not sure why I cannot figure out how to add code normally.

Edit 2: I am figuring I need to change the part that says:

```
 if (response == 'taken' ) {
    lastname_state = false;
    $('#lastname').parent().removeClass();
    $('#lastname').parent().addClass("form_error");
    $('#lastname').siblings("span").text('Sorry... lastname already taken');
```

to post something instead of text('Sorry... lastname already taken');